php script does not read "completed" status out of api request correctly
thanks for checking out my question. I created a PHP script that sends API requests via the DASH API. After the script sends its request, it should start a job on DASH. However, the script is having trouble retrieving the "completed" status properly and ends up running in a loop, continuously requesting the job status until the cron job is forced to end. The possible job statuses are "in progress," "completed," and "failed."
Here are the relevant parts of my script:
function create_batch_job($access_token, $asset_id, $batch_item_id)
{
    $batch_job_url = 'https://api-v2.dash.app/embeddable-link-batch-jobs';
    $headers = [
        "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];

    $body = json_encode([
        "items" => [
            [
                "batchItemId" => "my-item-$batch_item_id",
                "assetId" => $asset_id,
                "assetFileId" => null,
                "presetParameters" => []
            ]
        ],
        "transformationDescription" => [
            "type" => "CUSTOM",
            "candidateTransformations" => [
                [
                    "criteria" => [
                        [
                            "type" => "MATCHES_MEDIA_TYPES",
                            "mediaTypes" => [
                                ["type" => "image", "subType" => "png"]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "transformation" => []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    list($status, $response) = http_request('POST', $batch_job_url, $headers, $body);

    log_message("Request URL: $batch_job_url", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
    log_message("Request headers: " . json_encode($headers), $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
    log_message("Request body: $body", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
    log_message("Response status: $status", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
    log_message("Response body: $response", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);

    if ($status == 200) {
        log_api_response($response);
        $response_data = json_decode($response, true);
        return $response_data['id'];
    } else {
        log_api_response($response);
        throw new Exception('Batch job creation failed');
    }
}

function check_job_status($access_token, $job_id, $batch_item_id)
{
    $job_status_url = "https://api-v2.dash.app/embeddable-link-batch-jobs/$job_id";
    $headers = [
        "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];

    for ($attempt = 0; $attempt < 3; $attempt++) { 
        sleep(5); 
        log_message("Checking job status for URL: $job_status_url (Attempt " . ($attempt + 1) . "/3)", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);

        list($status_code, $response) = http_request('GET', $job_status_url, $headers);
        log_message("Check job status response: $status_code $response", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);

        if ($status_code == 200) {
            $response_data = json_decode($response, true);
            $status = $response_data['status'];

            if ($status === 'COMPLETED') {
                log_message("Job $job_id completed successfully.", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);

                
                $result_key = "my-item-$batch_item_id";
                if (isset($response_data['result']['results'][$result_key]['result']['url'])) {
                    $url = $response_data['result']['results'][$result_key]['result']['url'];
                    log_message("Job completed, URL: $url", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);

                    
                    file_put_contents('completed_jobs_urls.txt', "Job $job_id URL: $url\n", FILE_APPEND);

                    
                    return [$status, $response_data];
                } else {
                    log_message("Error: No URL found in the job response.", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
                }
            } elseif ($status === 'FAILED') {
                log_message("Job $job_id failed.", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
                return [$status, $response_data]; 
            } else {
                log_message("Job $job_id in progress... Status: $status", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Job status check failed');
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Job $job_id did not complete after 3 attempts");
}



function process_assets()
{
    global $csvFile, $completedJobsFile, $jobIdsFile;

    log_api_response("Cron job started successfully.");

    $access_token = authenticate();

    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csvFile));
    $header = array_shift($csv); 
    $outfile = fopen($completedJobsFile, 'w'); 
    fputcsv($outfile, ['jobId', 'status', 'url']); 

    $batch_item_id = 1; 

    foreach ($csv as $idx => $row) {
        $asset_id = $row[0]; 
        log_message("Processing asset " . ($idx + 1) . ": $asset_id", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);

        try {
            
            $job_id = create_batch_job($access_token, $asset_id, $batch_item_id);

            if ($job_id) {
                file_put_contents($jobIdsFile, "$job_id\n", FILE_APPEND);

                
                list($status, $response_data) = check_job_status($access_token, $job_id, $batch_item_id);

                if ($status === 'COMPLETED') {
                    
                    $result_key = "my-item-$batch_item_id";
                    if (isset($response_data['result']['results'][$result_key]['result']['url'])) {
                        $url = $response_data['result']['results'][$result_key]['result']['url'];
                        fputcsv($outfile, ['jobId' => $job_id, 'status' => $status, 'url' => $url]);
                        log_message("Job $job_id completed and saved to file.", $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
                    }
                }

                $batch_item_id++; 
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            log_message("Error processing asset ID $asset_id: " . $e->getMessage(), $GLOBALS['responseLogFile']);
        }
    }

    fclose($outfile); 
}


process_assets();

I wanted the script run one asset id at a time, extract the link i need and write the link + id into a csv file. But the script is unable to find the "completed" status in the api request, so all the following procedure is not happening either. Why is the script unable to find the "completed" statement from the api job?

Do you specifically mean that if ($status === 'COMPLETED') isn't producing the result you expect?  When you debug, what is the observed runtime value of $status?

"and ends up running in a loop" - which part, exactly? // It very much sounds and looks like you are trying to process an asynchronous result, in a synchronous fashion(?). Which you probably shouldn't do to begin with. Is there documentation available for this API?

As far as I can see this would only ever run check_job_status once, immediately after you've sent the job to the API. So the chances of it having completed already are low. Even with your retry mechanism, the retries will occur quite close to each other - and we don't know how long you expect these batch jobs to take. Then it'll give up and move to the next job. But if it has to retry multiple times on lots of jobs I can see why the cron job might time out - again we don't know what timeout value you've got on your PHP scripts in your config.

Wouldn't it be better to have a separate cron-triggered script which checks on the status of jobs? It should perhaps process one job at a time, then it doesn't time out - i.e. just processing the next incomplete one off the list. If you trigger it frequently it should still process them all in a reasonable timescale. And it could come back to ones it couldn't get a completed status for last time, and retry them. And you're likely to find it a lot easier to work with your stored status data if you put it into a database rather than relying on a text file.

According to the documentation (https://dash.redoc.ly/v2#operation/getAssetEmbeddableLinkBatchJob), there's not always a "status" field in the response. The values such as "IN_PROGRESS", "FAILED" and "COMPLETED" appear to be held in a field called "type" instead. The "status" field only seems to be present when the job type is "IN_PROGRESS" or "FAILED". It's not there when the type is "COMPLETED". Did you debug the code to see what the $status value in your code actually contains in each case you're trying to process, or what the rest of the response looked like? I'd guess perhaps not.

Thank you for pointing that out, @ADyson!
I reviewed the documentation again, and you’re right—the job state is held in the type field, not the status field, which explains why the code wasn’t behaving as expected. I’ve now updated my code to check the type field instead of status to determine whether a job is completed or still in progress and will test it again.

The problem lies in the check_job_status function which was checking the "status" field, when it should check the "type" field.
I changed the function to check for the type field and now its all working how it was supposed to be.
 if ($type === 'COMPLETED') instead of `if ($status === 'COMPLETED')`

